# It's a shah thing you wouldn't understand

Tags: slang

I found that sentence printed on a T-shirt :
IT'S A SHAH THING YOU WOULDN'T UNDERSTAND

I wonder how this ("Shah thing") should be understood.
Is it related to some slang originating in Indian or Iran ?
Or related to the fall and demise of the Shah, ruler of Iran, in 1979 ?
Or simply an adaptation of "It's a black thing, etc."

I made some research but couldn't find any other occurrence.

Comment: I believe the original saying is "It's a black thang you wouldn't understand" but not sure where that originated, other than I saw it on a shirt in the early 90's near Chicagoland.

Comment: There seem to be lots of shirts for sale on the Internet which say "It's a X thing, you wouldn't understand", where X is a common surname.  Is it possible that the person wearing the shirt was named Shah?

Answer (score 3):

This phrase has nothing to do with the former Iranian monarch: you find it because “Shah” is a common name and people who bear it are a large target market.

Many businesses engage in selling ‘personalized’ merchandise—a t-shirt or hoodie or coffee mug or some other sellable object imprinted with —the name of the buyer or of a group with which the buyer identifies—or with a catchphrase into which the name can be inserted.

*It's a X thing, you wouldn't understand* is one catchphrase popular with these merchandisers—presumably because it’s popular with their customers. The phrase means “That is a matter which only people who are *X* understand; since you are not *X* you cannot understand it”. It thus asserts the superiority of people who are *X* to people who are not *X*.

Such merchandise is usually available for just about any name, and marketed with internet links and images which embody most fairly common names—“Shah”, for instance. I was unable to find any merchandise for “kantx”, but [here](https://www.sunfrog.com/search/?cId=43&cName=LifeStyle&search=Smith)’s a website marketing hoodies and t-shirts with the name “Smith” inserted into many different catchphrases.

Comment: That doesn't explain why Shah in that instance. I wouldn't be so categorical. I suspect an alteration of "sure".